# How to convert a row into a column in mysql query without pivot

Tags: php, mysql, sql

How to convert  a row into a column in mysql query without pivot. I have a table schema like

```
***********************
ID   SchoolName

1     JV

2     SDH
***********************
```

I wanted to transpose this as

```
**1 JV 2 SDH**
```

I have tried pivot,but i need to find a alternative. Please help.

Comment: is there a condition for the rows?

Comment: What is this for ? Display only ? Then use PHP.

Comment: @LorenzMeyer. This is used for excel reports. Since the output is in excel format,I am unable to do that in php,so i need the relevant data in query itself.

Comment: You have to elaborate a bit. Post your table schema. Do you need to transpose only two rows? From your output it's unclear do you need one column, or four columns... etc.

Comment: [link](http://postimg.org/image/qs7a2liyp/).This is the exact table i needed the result.The output needed for that table must be like,

India USA Brazil.
all the row datas are changed to individual columns.

Comment: @GowthamRajan What values are you expecting in these columns (their respective ids)? Or you just need an empty resultset with column names equal to country names?

Comment: @peterm,Just i need to transpose row into columns,including id.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(ID, ' ', SchoolName) SEPARATOR ' ') AS OUTPUT
FROM YourTable
```

Answer (score 0):

Even based on your last comment it's still unclear what you are trying to achieve and that actually prevents you from getting an exact answer you're looking for.

Now if you just need to transpose your country table and present it as a single row you can do that with dynamic SQL

```sql
SET @sql = NULL;

SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(id, '`', country_name, '`'))
  INTO @sql
  FROM countries;

SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT ', @sql);

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Output:

```
| INDIA | USA | BRASIL |
------------------------
|     1 |   2 |      3 |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c99f1/1)** demo

Comment: @GowthamRajan Did it help? Do you need more help with your question?

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SELECT 
GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT_WS(' ',`ID`,`SchoolName`) ORDER BY `ID` ASC SEPARATOR ' ') gre
FROM 
tblstudents ;
```